# Can mustache iterate a top-level array?

Tags: javascript, mustache

My object looks like this:

```
['foo','bar','baz']
```

And I want to use a mustache template to produce from it something like this:

```
"<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li><li>baz</li></ul>"
```

But how? Do I really have to munge it into something like this first?

```
{list:['foo','bar','baz']}
```

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
Mustache.render('<ul>{{#.}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/.}}</ul>', ['foo','bar','baz']);
```

It also works for things like this...

```
var obj = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}];
var tmp = '<ul>{{#.}}<li>{{name}}</li>{{/.}}</ul>';
Mustache.render(tmp, obj);
```

Comment: actually the template comes first:

`Mustache.render('<ul>{{#.}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/.}}</ul>',['foo','bar','baz']);`

Comment: How do I get, for example, the 2nd element of the array? I'm trying to do {{.1}} with mustache.js and its not working.

Comment: NM, figured it out: you can just ignore the dots: so {{1}} or if you want to do a logical check, then {{#1}} whatever {{/1}}

Comment: Are these features documented somewhere? I don't see `{{.}}`, `{{1}}`, or anything similar in mustache(5).

Comment: Note: top level array is not supported by Hogan: https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/issues/74. Use the solution with a property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360440/470117

Comment: Solution for Java implementation of Mustache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235839

Answer (score 134):

I had the same problem this morning and after a little experimentation I discovered you can use the {{.}} to refer to the current element of an array:

```
<ul>
  {{#yourList}}
  <li>{{.}}</li>
  {{/yourList}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Where does the name of the #yourList variable come from? can you show a javascript sample of the actual rendering?

Comment: you don't even need to use "yourList", you can just use "." here too:
 `Mustache.render('<ul>{{#.}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/.}}</ul>',['foo','bar','baz']);`

Comment: The JavaScript would be
    `Mustache.render('<ul>{{#.}}{{.}}{{/.}}</ul>', {yourList: ['foo','bar','baz']});`

Comment: Note, only do this if you want less-readable templates. The accepted answer, albeit not "required" is a more readable solution.

Comment: Does anyone know why it is that this information is absent from the documentation? http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Comment: This is the answer that clarifies things better than the accepted answer, since it bother to mention what the dot character actually is.

Comment: I wish this was in the documentation!

Comment: It works only for array's not for objcts, impossible for `{a:'foo',b:'bar',c:'baz'}`... How to do anonymous references when iterationg objects?

Comment: what if foo bar and baz have attributes? How can I acces those?

Comment: Just about what I needed. Thanks @Andy

Answer (score 5):

Building on @danjordan's answer, this will do what you want:

```
Mustache.render('<ul>{{#.}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/.}}</ul>',['foo','bar','baz']);
```

returning:

```
<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li><li>baz</li></ul>
```

Comment: It works only for array's not for objcts, impossible for `{a:'foo',b:'bar',c:'baz'}`... How to do anonymous references when iterationg over objects?

Answer (score 3):

Following are the examples to render multi-dimensional array in a template:

**Example 1**

```
'use strict';

var Mustache = require('mustache');

var view = {test: 'div content', multiple : ['foo', 'bar'], multiple_2 : ['hello', 'world']};
var template = '<div>{{test}}</div><ul>{{#multiple}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/multiple}}</ul><ul>{{#multiple_2}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/multiple_2}}</ul>';

var output = Mustache.render(template, view);

console.log(output);
```

**Example 2**

```
'use strict';

var Mustache = require('mustache');

var view = {test: 'div content', multiple : [{name: 'foo', gender: 'male'}, {name: 'bar', gender: 'female'}], multiple_2 : [{text: 'Hello', append: '**', prepend: '**'}, {text: 'World', append: '**', prepend: '**'}]};
var template = '<div>{{test}}</div><ul>{{#multiple}}<li>Hello my name is {{name}}. And I am {{gender}}</li>{{/multiple}}</ul><ul>{{#multiple_2}}<li>{{prepend}}_{{text}}_{{append}}</li>{{/multiple_2}}</ul>';

var output = Mustache.render(template, view);

console.log(output);
```

For test run, save above examples in file called 'test.js', run following command in commandline

```
nodejs test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for an array named `Strengths`:

```
{
   "ViewModel": 
    {
       "StrengthsItems": 
        {
           "Strengths": ["Dedicated", "Resourceful", "Professional", "Positive"]
        }
    }
}
```

works for me like a charm is as following:

```
{{#ViewModel.StrengthsItems}}
    <p class="p4">{{Strengths}}</p>
{{/ViewModel.StrengthsItems}}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think mustache can do this!  (surprisingly)
You can iterate over a list of objects, and then access the attributes of each object, but you can't seem to iterate over a simple list of values!

So, you have to transform your list into:

```
[ {"value":"foo"},{"value":"bar"},{"value":"baz"} ]
```

and then your template would be:

```
<ul>
  {{#the_list}}
  <li>{{value}}</li>
  {{/the_list}}
</ul>
```

To me, this seems like a severe problem with Mustache -- any template system should be able to loop over a list of simple values!

Comment: You just need to use {{.}}. See my answer below.

Comment: The down-votes are misleading. This answer is correct in that {{.}} is not part of the mustache standard, though it is supported by some implementations. There is no portable way to do this.

Comment: this one is right, and very usefully for multidimensional rendering. Please find my example as below