# How to render mustache js from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I have a json with the following format. I want to fill that json in view using mustache js.

**Json Format**

[image]

Code for rendering json is

```
render: function () {
    var tmplData = self.jsonArrayFull;
    var out = Mustache.render(self._dashboardTemplate(), tmplData);
    self.element.html(out);
}

_dashboardTemplate: function () {
            var template = '<div id="layoutContainer" style="background-color:{{backgroundColor}}"></div>';
            return template;
        },
```

How can I do this? Its rendering null. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that `tmplData` is an array, not an object, so when your template looks for `{{backgroundColor}}`, that is a backgroundColor of array, which doesn't exist.

To solve this, either pick the first item in the array to pass to `Mustache.render` ie:

```
Mustache.render(self._dashboardTemplate(), tmplData[0])
```

Or put a loop into your template to render each array item like:

```
var template = '{{#.}}<div id="layoutContainer" style="background-color:{{backgroundColor}}"></div>{{/.}}';
```

See this question: [Can mustache iterate a top-level array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516297/can-mustache-iterate-a-top-level-array) for details about rendering a top level array.

Comment: @lanRoutledge If i want another item from that array. What can i do for that? for example, Now there is only background color, but i need the dashlet items also..

Comment: Dashlets is not another item in the array, it is a property of an object in that array. You could do something like: `var template = '{{#.}}<div id="layoutContainer" style="background-color:{{backgroundColor}}">{{#dashlets}}<div class="dashlet">{{.}}</div>{{/dashlets}}</div>{{/.}}';`(not tested)